# 10 journey card in Belgium. Can I use it between different stations, every trip?

Tags: trains, tickets, belgium

I am going to travel around Belgium and I was considering buying the [10 journey card](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/passes-cards/10-journey-card.aspx).

I read about it, but it seems that you can only use all the trips between 2 predefined stations.

It's not clear at all because I got the information from a friend that I could use it between any stations, each trip.

Anyone knows how this works?

Comment: I think Annoyed answer covered all the basics, but if you would expand on your specific needs (and age) I could maybe give you some more advice still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend probably simply meant another product, the “[rail pass](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/passes-cards/rail-pass.aspx)”:

> Travel alone or with others for the low price of only € 7.60 per trip. The Rail Pass takes you where and when you want to go.
>
> - Discount pass: 10 journeys for € 76 in 2nd class
> - To any destination in Belgium
> - 1 or more passengers on one Rail Pass
> - No restrictions for a year
> - More comfort: € 117 in 1st class

The 10-journey card can presumably be cheaper if you only travel on one route and follows slightly different rules (can be combined with family discounts, etc.) There is also the [Go Pass 10](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/passes-cards/go-pass-10.aspx), which is basically a “Rail pass” for people under 26 years of age and is even cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

The Belgian railway company NMBS/SNCB offers a variety of passes and cards. Depending on your needs, you might need a different pass or card. Following cards are available for **occasional trips**.

**Go Pass 10**

- Age 25 or lower
- Between *any* destination in Belgium (not including border stations)
- Priced at € 51

**Rail Pass (Go Pass equivalent for people over 25)**

- Any age
- Between *any* destination in Belgium (not including border stations)
- Priced at € 76

**10-Journey Card**

- Any age
- Between *two specific* stations (not including border stations)
- Price depends on the two stations

All passes and cards are valid for a single year and offer **10 journeys**. These journeys can be used by **multiple people at the same time** if compliant with the pass or card's restrictions. For example if you are 25 years old and your friend is 26 years old, you can not use the same pass. Unless both of you would use a Rail Pass.

More information can be found at the Belgian railroad's [official website](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/passes-cards.aspx).